# ios uiwebview stop request when shouldstartloadwithrequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am receiving shouldstartloadwithrequest event and I need to stop request for some conditions. How to stop uiwebview request when shouldstartloadwithrequest? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the condition, then return `NO` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. Make sure to set delegate appropriately and include the UIWebViewDelegate protocol in the interface of the delegate class.

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke the `stopLoading` method for the `UIWebView`. Below code will check if the webview is loading and stop it.

```
   if([webView isLoading]) {
      [webView stopLoading];
   }
```

**EDIT**: After re-reading your question, I understood you want to return `NO` in the request to stop it from beginning to load, so you would do something like:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    //Check your condition:
    if(myCondition == TRUE)
         return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: In this event, request is going to start so better return NO than stop webview loading. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Jaume Accept this as the answer if it suffices as the solution to your question. Thanks !

Comment: This would stop the entire page loading, not just  a portion of it.

Comment: @MartinH that's what the OP wanted, as you see he accepted the same solution.

Comment: He says stop "some conditions". Returning YES or NO from shouldStartLoadFromRequest allows you to choose which parts to load and which not, which is what I assumed "some conditions" meant.